# Display repeated field type in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a password repeated field type in Symfony2 form that goes like this:

```
                ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'invalid_message' => 'Les mots de passe doivent correspondre',
                'options' => array('required' => true),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'Mot de passe'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'Mot de passe (validation)'),
                'required' => $bRequired,
                'trim' => true,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Assert\Regex(array(
                        'pattern' => "/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9!?+]{8,15}$/",
                        'match' => true,
                        'message' => "msg"
                            )),
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                )
            ))
```

In twig I'm used to show this field like this:

```
{% for passwordField in form.password %}
    {{ form_row(passwordField,{'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to display the password field and the validation field **separately** so I can display them in different places in my form.

Comment: If you downvote at least explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is explained in doc:

```
// in your template.html.twig

/.../

{{ form_row(form.password.first,{'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
{{ form_row(form.password.second,{'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'} }) }}

/.../
```

where:

> The names first and second are the default names for the two sub-fields. However, these names can be controlled via the first_name and second_name options. If you've set these options, then use those values instead of first and second when rendering.